# Array of threads, only a few active at a time?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, .net-4.0, threadpool

Apologies if this is simple question, but Im extremely worn down and though thinking straight.  I recently set up threading and its working great.  The user selects items to have work performed on, and I dynamicaly create an array of `Thread`s for however many items they select and dispatch one thread per item.

However, I noticed that if too many are selected the server the files are on doesnt play nice.  I know for a fact that I can declare only 5 active threads a time, even if there are 30 items that need work, but I can't wrap my head around it.

PS: If Im describing ThreadPool let me know... Ive tried to get that to work but had a hell of a time and no luck, pretty new to .NET way of threading.

**Current way:**

```
threadedResults = new List<string>[SelectedItems.Count];
List<string> results = new List<string>();
ThreadSettings tsArgs = (ThreadSettings)args;

for (int i = 0; i < SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{
    threadedResults[i] = new List<string>();
}

Thread[] threads = new Thread[SelectedItems.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{
    KeyValuePair<int, ThreadSettings> threadArgs = new KeyValuePair<int, ThreadSettings>(i, (ThreadSettings)tsArgs);

    threads[i] = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoWork));
    threads[i].Start(threadArgs);
}
for (int i = 0; i < SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{
    if (CommandTask != null)
        threads[i].Join();
    else
    {
        // User Cancelled, abort all threads and break
        for (int j = 0; j < SelectedItems.Count; j++)
        {
            threads[j].Abort();
        }
        break;
    }
}

// Gather all results, format and return
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, avoid `Abort()` at all costs.  Have your threads handle an event or cancellation token instead if possible.

Comment: What version of .NET?  TPL is much easier for many common threading tasks.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare .Net 4.0, and thanks for the abort tip

Comment: Then I would look at the TPL library, as @JamesMichaelHare suggested

Comment: Keep in mind, also, that no matter how many tasks/threads you create, the number that can actually run concurrently together is somewhat limited by what you're trying to do, hardware, etc.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare Right, I want to limit it because 30 at once is too many for the server connecting to.  So I figure do 5 at once 6 times

Comment: That's the beauty of using Task in the TPL, it creates "units of work" instead of threads (directly), it manages those tasks on the threads according to your server's configuration so you don't have to.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare Ive been looking at examples for TPL, but it seems like they are either way too simple or way too complicated... do you have a link handy of something like what I want to do?

Comment: I think you will find the discussion on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282989/question-regarding-threading-background-workers) helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you'd want to do something like this in the TPL:

```
        // source for cancelling work
        var cxlSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        // create and schedule tasks to start
        var tasks =
            Enumerable.Range(0, SelectedItems.Count)
                .Select(i => Task.Factory.StartNew(DoWork, yourStateInfo, cxlSource.Token))
                .ToArray();

        // then wait for the results
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

If at any time, you need to cancel the tasks, you can request a cancel:

```
            cxlSource.Cancel();
```

Which will prevent any tasks awaiting execution from starting, and your tasks can examine the token themselves periodically so they can abort early if cancelled while in progress.

There's a lot of nuance to using the TPL (and threading in general), but that's a *rough* idea.

Comment: That almost seems toooooo easy :P haha Ill give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @Hershizer33: That's the beauty of the TPL, it makes threading much simpler.  Don't get me wrong, there's still a bit of a learning curve (as there is with new things like LINQ, lambdas, etc), but once you learn it it's really powerful and elegant.

Comment: Quick question. So that looks like to me it will being opening tasks from 0 to SelectedItems.Count (Say 30)... so how many will be active at once?  All 30?

Comment: @Hershizer33: They will all be scheduled, but .NET runtime will decide based on the hardware how many threads will be in the pool to allow tasks to run concurrently.  Basically they will all be queued to run, then the thread pool will begin executing them in parallel with as many threads as it can with your configuration.

Comment: Ah... I ask because DoWork opens a SSH connection to a unix server and runs a grep command, and my Unix admin has asked to only do like 4 or 5 at a time instead of all 30

Comment: @Hershizer33: It shouldn't run all 30 at once, you could get around that restriction, though, in several ways.  You could guard the code that opens the unix connection with a `Semaphore`, that would limit entry into that block to only X at a time, or you could create a custom TaskScheduler to limit the number of tasks scheduled (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx).  If you are doing other things besides the unix connection, I'd say use the sempahore to just limit that portion but let potentially other things happen in parallel.

Comment: @Hershizer33 If you are worried about that, try `Parallel.Invoke` with `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`. Or, just use a semaphore in your task implementation to limit how many parallel threads can enter the section of code you wish to be "not too parallel". Oh, and here is a very good [introduction to TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963553.aspx).

Comment: @Hershizer33: By the way, a great intro book to this is `.NET 4 Parallel Programming in C#`, covers the TPL, concurrent collections, synchronization mechanisms (such as `Semaphore`), etc...

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare Thanks a ton for sticking this one out with me you've been extremely helpful.  Trying out your ideas now.

Comment: @JamesMichealHare This seems to be working great! A quick note on the code, I had to do `Task.Factory.StartNew` to get it to work (it didnt like `TaskFactory.StartNew`)

Comment: @Hershizer33: My bad, i must have forgot to type the `.`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to you version, I would declare Environment.ProcessorCount number of threads, instead of 5 (if you have 2 processors, only 2 of the 5 threads will be running on the same time). Too many threads causes overhead in the system (and that may be the problem for you).

If not, consider using Task in .net 4, or the TreadPool.

Comment: Using the processor count makes sense for compute-bound tasks.  But this question concerns I/O, for which processor count is worse than useless.